# wso2 4.1 APM is getting Event-Hub status code Error during start

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using the wso2 API manager 4.1 and deployed 2 instance as HA.
In one of my instance, most of the time, starting the wso2 will get following error, which caused all the API request falls into this server return 404 resource not found error. The wired thing is sometimes restart this wso2 instance will not have such error. Does anyone have idea about this?

=====

```
2022-10-20T14:47:46,224 [-] [Thread-3]  WARN SSLUtilBase The trusted certificate with alias [luxtrustglobalrootca] and DN [CN=LuxTrust Global Root, O=LuxTrust s.a., C=LU] is not valid due to [NotAfter: Wed Mar 17 17:51:37 SGT 2021]. Certificates signed by this trusted certificate WILL be accepted
2022-10-20T14:47:48,483 [-] [Thread-38] ERROR PolicyUtil Error in retrieving throttle policies
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer.exception.ThrottlePolicyDeployerException: Event-Hub status code is : 404
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer.PolicyRetriever.getPolicies(PolicyRetriever.java:203) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer.PolicyRetriever.getAllSubscriptionPolicies(PolicyRetriever.java:87) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer.utils.PolicyUtil.deployAllPolicies(PolicyUtil.java:159) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer.utils.ThrottlePolicyStartupListener.run(ThrottlePolicyStartupListener.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.policy.deployer_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2022-10-20T14:47:48,496 [-] [pool-155-thread-6] ERROR SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain: carbon.super. Received response with status code 404
2022-10-20T14:47:48,496 [-] [Thread-3] ERROR APILoggerManager Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain : carbon.super
2022-10-20T14:47:48,500 [-] [pool-155-thread-7] ERROR SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain: carbon.super. Received response with status code 404
2022-10-20T14:47:48,501 [-] [pool-155-thread-2] ERROR SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain: carbon.super. Received response with status code 404
2022-10-20T14:47:48,501 [-] [pool-155-thread-1] ERROR SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain: carbon.super. Received response with status code 404
2022-10-20T14:47:48,508 [-] [pool-155-thread-3] ERROR SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Could not retrieve subscriptions for tenantDomain: carbon.super. Received response with status code 404
2022-10-20T14:47:48,508 [-] [pool-155-thread-6]  WARN SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /subscription-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving subscription. Retrying after 15 seconds.
2022-10-20T14:47:48,508 [-] [pool-155-thread-3]  WARN SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /applications from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving subscription. Retrying after 15 seconds.
2022-10-20T14:47:48,508 [-] [Thread-3] ERROR APILoggerManager Error while calling internal service API
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while retrieving subscription from /api-logging-configs
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.APILoggerManager.invokeService_aroundBody10(APILoggerManager.java:140) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.APILoggerManager.invokeService(APILoggerManager.java:98) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.APILoggerManager.initializeAPILoggerList_aroundBody0(APILoggerManager.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.APILoggerManager.initializeAPILoggerList(APILoggerManager.java:56) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the Traffic Manager configurations correctly pointing servers to each other?

```
[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://control-plane-host:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://control-plane-host:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://control-plane-host:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://control-plane-host:9711"]
```

Double-check the steps in [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/#configure-the-gateway-nodes) section.

Comment: Thanks for point out the setting. Our HA setup is using Active-Active mode . So I added the [apim.throttling] and [apim.throttling.url_group] setting accordingly. but still got error and the error becomes "org.wso2.andes.AMQTimeoutException: Server did not respond in a timely fashion".

BTW, our wso2 4.1 is migrate from 3.2 by following [https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/320-to-410/upgrading-from-320-to-410/#step-3-migrate-the-identity-components]. And the doc does not mentioned anything about the [apim.throttling] settings in deployment.yoml.